# PHP MongoClient Connect Replica Set With Authentication

Tags: php, mongodb

I am simple trying to connect to mongo a run a simple read query with no success.

I am using:

- Mongo 3.0.3
- PHP 5.6.9
- Ubuntu Linux Server OS

I have servers on:

- AWS Ubuntu web-server
- Google Cloud Mongo replica set cluster (5 boxes, 1 arbiter)

I am using examples from documentation from:

PHP Replica Sets: http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.connecting.rs.php

PHP Authentication: http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.connecting.auth.php

Here is the code:

```
$this->mongooe = new \MongoClient('mongodb://mongo-1.mongo.example.com:27017,
        mongo-2.mongo.example.com:27017,
        mongo-3.mongo.example.com:27017,
        mongo-4.mongo.example.com:27017,
        mongo-5.mongo.example.com:27017', 
        [
            'replicaSet'=> 'exampleSet', 
            'db'        => 'example', 
            'username'  => 'example-admin', 
            'password'  =>'123456'
        ]);
```

I get this error in my logs:

`[Mon Nov 23 17:56:23.864370 2015] [:error] [pid 2480] [client 192.168.56.1:61512] [2015-11-23 17:56:23] .ERROR: mongo-1.mongo.example.com:27017: not authorized for query on example.history {"exception":"[object] (MongoCursorException(code: 13): mongo-1.mongo.example.com:27017: not authorized for query on example.history at /media/sf_api_admin/app/Controller/V1/Example/Config.php:66)"} [], referer: http://localhost:8042/example/configs`

Though I have tried 8 different syntax configurations like this one:

```
$this->mongooe = new \MongoClient('mongodb://example-admin:123456@mongo-1.mongo.example.com:27017,
        example-admin:123456@mongo-2.mongo.example.com:27017,
        example-admin:123456@mongo-3.mongo.example.com:27017,
        example-admin:123456@mongo-4.mongo.example.com:27017,
        example-admin:123456@mongo-5.mongo.example.com:27017', 
        [
            'replicaSet'=> 'exampleSet', 
            'db'        => 'example'
        ]);
```

I also get this error: `No candidate servers found`

My example-admin has the following roles:

- dbAdmin
- dbOwner
- read
- readWrite
- userAdmin

(basically full access, just for testing)

There something really stupid I am missing, someone help me out?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It is simple solution.

Do this:

`sudo apt-get install pkg-config libssl-dev
 sudo pecl install mongodb-1.2.0alpha3`

and dont forget to include mongodb.so in php.ini file.

For this new versions of mongo you need to use alpha version of build.